# Can php have an interface inside a class?

Tags: php, zend-framework, class, interface

i would like to know if it is possible to have a function in PHP which returns an interface or a class which contains an interface?

i tried something like this, but it fails

```
<?php
//class for list of controllers for ACL
class Gestionale_Action_Helper_Crud extends Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Abstract {

     interface crud_controller
    {
        public function indexAction();
        public function modificaAction();
        public function cancellaAction();
        public function creaAction();
    }


    public function getCrudInterface(){
        return $this->crud_controller;
    }
}
```

what i wanted to do, in zend framework, create an interface that crud controllers must implement, or even better if i could create an abstract controller and have them implement that

thank you

Comment: I'm afraid you can't place an interface inside of a class, like this. Sorry - Ultimately what are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to create in zend framework an abstract model for CRUD operations and an interface for CRUD controllers, this way instead of writing same code for 10 different tables, i would just extend the model, implement the interface and configure it to the specific table :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the interface outside of any class (preferably in a different file) and let it be implemented by all your crud-controllers.

```
<?php
class GrudController implements CrudInterface
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: where could i place it so that zend framework would include it?

Comment: Well you could place it in your controller directory and manually include/require it OR (prettier) configure the autoloader in your bootstrap class to search a different library folder for classes/interfaces. It could be placed in /library/YourName/Controller/Action/Interface and named YourName_Controller_Action_Interface (the zf autoloader converts underscores to directory-separators by default.)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that you use `Zend_Rest_Controller` instead of creating your own interface.

`Zend_Rest_Controller` is an abstract class that defines five basic methods you need in a CRUD-controller: `index`, `get`, `post`, `put`, and `delete`.

Combined with `Zend_Rest_Route` it lets you create nice and clean RESTful application.

You can get more reading on `Zend_Rest_Controller` at http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework.html and http://techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework

Comment: yeah, i didn't knew of it at the time, i implemented my own rest_controller as an abstract class which does almost everything automatically, just a few config variables, still nice to know zend thought of this too

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure i get what it is you want to do, but i'm fairly certain you're asking the wrong question. if you simply want to make sure an object implements a certain interface, this is quite easy to do. lets say for example you have some helper method in a class which deals with a crud controller, you just specify the type in the argument list:

```
class crud_helper {
    public function help(crud_controller $cc) {
        $cc->indexAction();
    }
}
```

now you can pass any object that is an instance of a class that implements crud_controller to the method help. but no other object.

Comment: even though this isn't what i needed, it's a nice idea i'll keep it in mind :)